# What is the thread breakdown for a Java app running on t2.large EC2

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-ec2, jvm

I'm trying to understand just how much performance I could expect from a t2.large, t2.xlarge or t2.2xlarge instance running a Java app.

Suppose I have an app running on a t2.large instance that is receiving `x` requests per second. How many threads can or will be created to fulfill these requests as fast as possible?

AWS states that a t2.large has 2 vCPUs and that a vCPU is a single thread on an Intel Xeon processor. If that's the case then how many JVM threads can a single Xeon thread handle?

Answer (score 0):

there is no hard limit on how many JVM Threads a single core (or virtual core) can execute. Multiple threads can be executed on the same core after each other. This does not even necessarily has to slow down your application. E.g. if your current thread is wating for an IO-operation to return e.g. a waiting for a response from a Database query or an HTTP call, the thread can be suspended as it is not possible to execute anything in the thread anyway and another thread can take over the time on the CPU.

It depends on the type of work to be executed in your application and on the throughput of parallel requests how many threads are reasonable to run on the given amount of 2 vCPUs.

The best way to understand the limits will be to measure the throughput and response time with different workloads.